# Web parts are not displayed on the new PnPClientSidePage

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, team-sites

I'm trying to get "webParts" from the client's site to see which ones are present and then delete the selected ones. The problem is that when the page is new the script does not find any elements. The strange thing is, that it finds elements only when someone makes some manual edit on Home page. I have all the permissions to the site.

I also tried the other way, i.e. adding a new web part to the page, but I got an error:
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Here is the same situation: if someone manually edits the home page, I can already add new web parts

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceUrl -Credentials $global:credentials
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx"
$webParts = $page.Controls

foreach ($webpart in $webparts) {
 $webpart.Title
}
```

Comment: How is the new page added? Manually or via a script?

Comment: Manually  by another person

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov do you have idea why is happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

This command allows the retrieval of a modern sitepage along with its properties and contents on it. Note that for a newly created modern site, the Columns and Sections of the Home.aspx page will not be filled according to the actual site page contents. This is because the underlying CanvasContent1 will not be populated until the homepage has been edited and published. The reason for this behavior is to allow for the default homepage to be able to be updated by Microsoft as long as it hasn't been modified. For any other site page or after editing and publishing the homepage, this command will return the correct columns and sections as they are positioned on the site page.

https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/599